# Limitar datos de entrada de usuario

Tags: c#

estoy aprendiendo a programar realmente soy muy novato en la programación en c#, he estado practicando y haciendo unos ejercicios en la consola por ejemplo este
Console.Write("Ingresa tu nombre: ");

```
        string nombre = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine($"Tu nombre es {nombre}");
```

La cuestión es, si quiero limitar la entrada del usuario, es decir que cuando el usuario escriba su nombre lo escriba digamos bien por ejemplo Pedro  y no escriba algo como P3/dr' y si escribe algo como esto no permita avanzar a la siguinte linea de codigo, que mande un mensaje diciendo que no esta perimitido numeros ni caracteres especiales, se me ocurre que en el if podría hacerlo ,pero realmente no tengo idea de como hacerlo,como limitar eso a que el usuario no escriba números o caracteres especiales..Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme...Saludos

Answer (score 1):

podrias usar una condición de manera rapida segun ejemplo con expresión regular.

```
string nombre = Console.ReadLine();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"/^[ñA-Za-z]*[ñA-Za-z][ñA-Za-z]*$/");

if (regex.IsMatch(compare))
{ 
       //true
        Console.WriteLine($"Tu nombre es {nombre}");
}
else {
//false
        Console.WriteLine($"Tu nombre no es valido.");
}
```

espero te ayude.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Me ha servido bastante tu información.
Aprovechando, sabrás como hago para eliminar los espacios en blanco entre dos palabras por ejemplo.
Console.Write("Introduce tu nombre: ");

```
        string nombre = Console.ReadLine();

        string nombreconvertido = nombre.Trim();

        Console.WriteLine($"Tu nombre es: {nombreconvertido}");
```

Estoy practicando en consola, y quisiera que el usuario ingresara su nombre, pero si lo ingresara de forma con espacio por ejemplo si pone:     Hector    Alan
Quisiera que en la salida solo se muestre la información sin espacios, asi Hector Alan.
Estuve checando y vi que con el Trim se eliminaban los espacios, pero solo se eliminan de una palabra si pongo dos ya no funciona.
Espero puedas ayudarme.Saludos

Comment: por favor no utilices el apartado de respuestas para comentarios, como podrás notar cada respuesta tiene la opción de `añade un comentario` en la cual puedes pedir o brindar información adicional.